# EJB injection - JNDI lookup fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jndi, lookup

So I'm starting to develop a Java EE Enterprise Application with Netbeans 8.2. It's about a shop, where you have a shopping cart and you have to store each client's session correctly.

In NetBeans I have: `Shop-ejb` and `Shop-war`.

`Shop-ejb` contains the following classes:

- `CartLocal.java`

  ```
  package cart;

  @Local
  public interface CartLocal{
  }
  ```
- `CartBean.java`

  ```
  package cart;

  @Stateful
  @StatefulTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 20)
  public class CartBean implements CartLocal{
  }
  ```

Then, `Shop-war` contains the following servlet:

- `Servlet.java`

  ```
  import cart.CartLocal;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;
  import javax.naming.InitialContext;
  import javax.naming.NamingException;
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.*;

  @WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/Servlet"})
  public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final String CARRITO_SESSION_KEY = "shoppingCart";

  public Servlet() {
      super();
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      CartLocal carrito = (CartLocal) request.getSession().getAttribute(CARRITO_SESSION_KEY);

      try {
          if (carrito == null) {
              InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
              carrito = (CartLocal) ic.lookup("java:global/Shop/Shop-ejb/CartBean!cart.CartLocal");

              request.getSession().setAttribute(CARRITO_SESSION_KEY, carrito);
          }
      } catch (NamingException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
  ```

I'm using GlasshFish, and when I access to `http://localhost:8080/Shop-war/Servlet` I get the following error on the NetBeans console:

```
Grave:   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/Shop/Shop-ejb/CartBean!cart.CartLocal' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Shop]
```

I know the `lookup` is failing but I tried multiple things, without result. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup an `<ejb-local-ref>` tag on your web.xml:

For example:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>CartLocal</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local>cat.CartLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>CartLocal</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

And access via lookup:

```
try {
        if (carrito == null) {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            carrito = (CartLocal) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/CartLocal");

            request.getSession().setAttribute(CARRITO_SESSION_KEY, carrito);
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, fixed my error, but I don't understand why this works and my code not